# Function "Reflection" C++

Tags: c++, templates, reflection, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <type_traits>

namespace reflection {
    typedef void (*__unknown_func)();
    typedef std::pair<__unknown_func, size_t> __pair_type;

    std::map<std::string, __pair_type> functions;

    template<typename K, typename V>
    inline bool mapContains(const std::map<K, V>& __map, const K& __key) noexcept {
        return __map.find(__key) != __map.end();
    }

    template<typename _Ret, typename ... _Args>
    inline void addFunction(const std::string& function_name, _Ret (*__func)(_Args...)) noexcept {
        functions.insert_or_assign(function_name, __pair_type(reinterpret_cast<__unknown_func >(__func), sizeof...(_Args)));
    }

    template<typename _Ret, typename ... _Args>
    _Ret callFunction(const std::string& function_name, const _Args& ... arguments) {
        if (!mapContains(functions, function_name)) {
            // I handle here
        }

        if (sizeof...(_Args) != functions[function_name].second) {
            // I handle here
        }

        //  ------------ Any way to check if the argument are compatible here??? ------------


        return reinterpret_cast<_Ret (*)(_Args...)>(functions[function_name].first)(arguments...);
    }

}

int testFunction(long argument) {
    try {
        std::cout << "Success! Argument value: " << argument << std::endl;
    } catch (...) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(const int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    reflection::addFunction("run", testFunction);
    reflection::callFunction<int>("run", 93321);
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

And it is completely functional.

Although, if I were not to call run with the wrong arguments: 
i.e. like this: 
`reflection::callFunction("run", (std::vector<int>)93321);`,
 it would print out a random number as the "Argument value: " in `testFunction`.

I know it's because of the `reinterpret_cast`s, since that's how that type of cast works, but I would still like to know if there is some type of workaround to this so that I can handle improper arguments.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Nits: all those `std::move`s in `addFunction` don't seem to do anything. Everything you're `std::move`ing (i.e. everything you're casting to rvalue) is already an rvalue. Also, checking for `_Ret = void` is unnecessary. The specializations `callFunction<void, Args...>` are all declared to return `void`. A function declared to return `void` *can* contain `return expr;` statements, as long as the `expr`s are themselves `void` (this is to support your use case). You can just say `return reinterpret_cast<_Ret (*)(Args...)>(...)(...);` and it should work. Anyway, have you seen `std::type_info`?

Comment: @HTNW Yeah, I have seen std::type_info. Although, I'm not sure how to go about doing it (i.e. what if function takes in base class but they give a sub class). Would you?

Comment: Oh, hm. That (handling subclasses) wouldn't be supported by `std::type_info`. I'm not entirely sure that's even possible...